# Bootstrap not applying CSS using Webpack

Tags: css, node.js, webpack, bootstrap-4, loader

I'm using Bootstrap with webpack, but when I run my app, no Bootstrap and no CSS is applied.

This is my webpack.config.js  :

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
var OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    // mode: 'production',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        publicPath: '',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, './build'),
        compress: true,
        port: 3000
    },
    performance: {
        maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
        maxAssetSize: 512000
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
              test: /\.s?css$/,
              use: [
                {
                  loader: "file-loader",
                  options: {
                    name: "[name].css"
                  }
                },
                {
                  loader: "extract-loader"
                },
                {
                  loader: "css-loader", 
                },
                {
                  loader: "sass-loader"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              use: {
                loader: "babel-loader"
              }
            },
            {
              test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
              use: ["file-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|otf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [
                  {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                      name: '[name].[ext]',
                      outputPath: 'fonts/'
                    }
                  }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
     //remove comments from JS files
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            uglifyOptions: {
            output: {
                comments: false,
            },
            },
        }),
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
            cssProcessorPluginOptions: {
            preset: ['default', { discardComments: { removeAll: true } }],
            }
        })
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css"
        }),
        new ManifestPlugin(),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve('./public/index.html'),
        }),
    ]
};
```

I have this kind of error in brower console :

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
CssSyntaxError

(192:1) Unknown word
```

I don't have an idea where this error comes from.

Comment: Please do not copy+paste chatty material to questions in order to defeat the content length filter. If the editor says you need to edit the question, please do so meaningfully.

Answer (score 1):

Below two versions of dev/prod and all the code you can see here [webpack-boilerplate](https://github.com/tomik23/webpack-boilerplate/blob/master/config/webpack.prod.js#L107)

**Dev:**

```
{
  test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        importLoaders: 2,
        sourceMap: true
      },
    },
    {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
      },
    }
  ],
},
```

**Prod:**

```
{
  test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
  use: [
    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        importLoaders: 2
      },
    },
    {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
      },
    },
  ],
},
```

Comment: hey, thank you.  when can i use both of these codes please ?

Comment: The first is the development version and the second is the production version.
You have it described in detail in the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/)